# jOOQ - how to use .whereNotExists() properly?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I want to persist daily close entities, representing close prices of stocks.

```
public class DailyData {
    private Long       id;
    private String     ticker;
    private BigDecimal open;
    private BigDecimal high;
    private BigDecimal low;
    private BigDecimal close;
    private Timestamp  date;
    //getters, setters
}
```

Because of the limited API of the data provider, I may get duplicate entries for certain dates (if, for example, I only need two days,  I still need to ask for a month worth of data). Obviously, I only want to have one record per date, so any date that already exists in the DB should not be persisted.

This may have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569846/jooq-insert-into-where-not-exists-for-postgres), but I am having trouble implementing it in practice. In particular, I don't understand how to pass actual values to be persisted. This is adapted from the example in the link:

```
Param<Integer> myId = param("date", Timestamp.class);
create.insertInto(DATA, DATA.TICKER, DATA.OPEN, DATA.HIGH, DATA.LOW, DATA.CLOSE, DATA.DATE)
            .select(
                    select(
                            date,
                            param("ticker", DATA.TICKER.getType()),
                            param("open", DATA.OPEN.getType()),
                            param("high", DATA.HIGH.getType()),
                            param("low", DATA.LOW.getType()),
                            param("close", DATA.CLOSE.getType()),
                            param("date", DATA.DATE.getType())
                    )
                            .whereNotExists(
                                    selectOne()
                                            .from(DATA)
                                            .where(DATA.DATE.eq(date))
                            )
            );
```

1. Where are the actual values passed on in the example? There is no call to .values() DSL command, which normally appears in jOOQ documentation to tell it what values are to be inserted.
2. Is .execute at the end not needed?
3. There is a batchInsert() command to persist many entities/rows at once. Is there a batch variety of the above mentioned example? Or do I simply have to iterate through all the entities and perform the uniqueness check on each one separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Where are the actual values passed on in the example? There is no call to .values() DSL command, which normally appears in jOOQ documentation to tell it what values are to be inserted.

Why are you using the named parameter API through `DSL.param()`? Just pass `DSL.val()` and you'll be fine. E.g.

```
select(
    date,
    val(ticker),
    val(open),
    val(high),
    val(low),
    val(close),
    val(date)
)
```

In fact, there is also a [`DSL.param(String, T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#param-java.lang.String-T-) method, which you could use to pass actual values.

Probably there should be more overloads. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7136

However, this query is probably better implemented using `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT` in PostgreSQL. [See also my answer to this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48619318/521799).

> 2. Is .execute at the end not needed?

Yes it is.

> 3. There is a batchInsert() command to persist many entities/rows at once. Is there a batch variety of the above mentioned example? Or do I simply have to iterate through all the entities and perform the uniqueness check on each one separately?

You can batch any statement. The relevant documentation is here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution

Comment: I may have misunderstood your original answer, but this clarified it. Also, I am just starting with jOOQ. But it works now, thanks. I now have a followup question. Is it possible to extend the above query for the situation, where a row should not be inserted or updated based on a column? Something like:

Insert the row if 'date' doesn't already exist. If it exists AND 'realtime close' column is true, update the close, otherwise do nothing.

The first part is already covered by the existing query, but the second part with if...update.. is not and I am not sure if it can be done like this.

Comment: @JozefMorvay. Glad it worked. Would you mind asking a new question here on Stack Overflow? They don't run out of question IDs anytime soon :) (the comments feature is not really well suited for Q&A)

Comment: one can never be careful enough :) I have created the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584925/jooq-how-to-use-wherenotexists-with-conditional-update)