# jOOQ - how to use .whereNotExists() with conditional update?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have a following jOOQ query, originally composed with the help of [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563726/jooq-how-to-use-wherenotexists-properly) question.

```
create.insertInto(DATA,DATA.TICKER,DATA.OPEN,DATA.HIGH,DATA.LOW,DATA.CLOSE,DATA.DATE)
.select(
    select(
        val(dailyData.getTicker()),
        val(dailyData.getOpen()),
        val(dailyData.getHigh()),
        val(dailyData.getLow()),
        val(dailyData.getClose()),
        val(dailyData.getDate())
        )
    .whereNotExists(
        selectOne()
        .from(DATA)
        .where(DATA.DATE.eq(dailyData.getDate()))
    )
).execute();
```

This query works properly. In addition, I would like to modify to accomplish the following feat, but I am not certain it is actually doable. In simple english:

"Insert the row if a row with the same 'date' column doesn't already exist in the table. If it exists AND 'realtime close' column is true, update the 'close', otherwise do nothing."

The first part is already covered by the existing query, but the second part with if...update... is not and that's what I need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain PostgreSQL, you would write this query as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO data (ticker, open, high, low, close, date)
VALUES (:ticker, :open, :high, :low, :close, :date)
ON CONFLICT (date)
DO UPDATE SET close = false WHERE close
```

This translates to the following jOOQ query:

```jooq
DSL.using(configuration)
   .insertInto(DATA)
   .columns(
       DATA.TICKER, 
       DATA.OPEN,
       DATA.HIGH,
       DATA.LOW,
       DATA.CLOSE,
       DATA.DATE)
   .values(
       dailyData.getTicker(),
       dailyData.getOpen(),
       dailyData.getHigh(),
       dailyData.getLow(),
       dailyData.getClose(),
       dailyData.getDate())
   .onConflict()
   .doUpdate()
   .set(DATA.CLOSE, inline(false))
   .where(DATA.CLOSE)
   .execute();
```

Comment: After a slight modification, it appears to have accomplished exactly what I was looking for. Thank you yet again. It would not have occurred to me that what I really needed was a completely different query.