# Can you prevent an insert in an after trigger in pgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, database-trigger

In postgres, I have an after-insert trigger on a partitionned table that checks if the record is unique or not.
Currently, if the record is not unique, the trigger raises an exception.
This is not what I want because I just want to ignore this case and act as if the insertion actually happened.

Is it possible to configure the trigger to silently fail ?
The surrounding transaction should not fail, but the row should not be inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an after-insert trigger on a partitionned table that checks if the record is unique or not.

You could do this as part of your `insert` statement, using the `on conflict do nothing` clause. This is simpler and more efficient than using a trigger.

For this to work, you need a `unique` constraint on the column (or the tuple of columns) whose uniqueness you want to enforce. Assuming that this is column `id`, you would do:

```
insert into mytable(id, ...)    -- enumerate the target columns here
values(id, ...)                 -- enumerate the values to insert here
on conflict(id) do nothing
```

Note that conflict action `do nothing` does not actually requires specifiying a conflict target, so strictly speaking you could just write this as `on conflict do nothing` instead. I find that it is always a good idea to specify the conflict target, so the scope is better defined.

---

If for some reason, you cannot have a unique index on the target column, then another option is to use the `insert ... select` syntax along with a `not exists` condition:

```
insert into mytable(id, ...)
select id, ...
from (values(id, ...)) t(id, ...)
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately Postgres unique index MUST include the partitionning field which is a timestamp in my case, so I can't use that solution.

Comment: @MMacphail: ok. I updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late I had a busy month. Your solution is working super fine! Thank you very much.
I'm using jooq so this is the refence implementation if ever: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569846/jooq-insert-into-where-not-exists-for-postgres